# What's the fastest way to create a transparent line in UIKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics

This one:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, 1)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
view.alpha = 0.1;
```

or this one:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, 1)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.1];
```

or is there any third alternative? Using a UIImageView with image? Doing custom drawing with CoreGraphics? What is supposed to be fastest?

Comment: I don't know about fastest but you might want to include NSBezierPath in your testing since that's what some Apple sample code uses for simple line drawing.

Comment: Have you tried using a CALayer? this is a lighter object that a UIView and uses less memory. I suspect it will draw faster than a UIView.

Comment: Do you just want to draw the line, or do you need to do a lot of manipulation of that line afterwards?

Comment: No manipulation. Just set a color and its alpha/opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be to create a CALayer. Using this will allow you to easily alter its color/opacity if needed.

```
CALayer *line = [CALayer new];
line.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, 1.0);
line.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1].CGColor;
[someView.layer addSublayer:line];
```

If you want to draw a line right onto an existing view and have it stay there with no altering you can add the following code to the drawRect: method of the existing view:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```